# ADSL connection drops - D-Link 2750U

Tags: networking, router, adsl, adsl-router

So lately I've been having major issues with my ISP about my connection.

My D-Link 2750U router reports the following attenuation:

```
+------------------+------------+-----------+
| Attenuation (dB) | Downstream | Upstream  |
+------------------+------------+-----------+
|                  |        365 |       183 |
+------------------+------------+-----------+
```

My ISP says that this is false and that the attenuation on my line is ~18dB (I am 27km away from my internet exchange which means attenuation around 37.5dB or so I'm told).

The following is a transcript of the log on my router from the last hour:

```
May 24 17:27:44 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
May 24 17:27:44 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: XTM Link Information, portid = 0, State = DOWN, Service Support = ATM
May 24 17:27:44 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: Connection DOWN, LinkActiveStatus=0x0
May 24 17:27:45 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
May 24 17:27:55 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
May 24 17:27:59 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
May 24 17:28:04 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
May 24 17:28:05 user    info    kernel: device atm0.1 left promiscuous mode
May 24 17:28:05 user    info    kernel: device atm0 left promiscuous mode
May 24 17:28:05 user    info    kernel: br0: port 6(atm0.1) entering disabled state
May 24 17:28:06 daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. Connection DOWN.
May 24 17:28:06 daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. PPP connection DOWN.
May 24 17:28:10 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
May 24 17:28:19 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
May 24 17:28:24 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
May 24 17:28:28 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 message exchange
May 24 17:28:29 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link up, Bearer 0, us=507, ds=4096
May 24 17:28:29 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: XTM Link Information, portid = 0, State = UP, Service Support = ATM
May 24 17:28:29 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmrt: MAC address: cc b2 55 45 e5 c4
May 24 17:28:29 user    warn    kernel: [DoCreateDeviceReq.2367]: register_netdev
May 24 17:28:29 user    warn    kernel: [DoCreateDeviceReq.2369]: register_netdev done
May 24 17:28:29 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: Connection UP, LinkActiveStatus=0x1, US=507000, DS=4096000
May 24 17:28:29 user    warn    kernel: BCMVLAN : atm0 mode was set to RG
May 24 17:28:29 user    warn    kernel: [ERROR vlan] bcmVlan_insertTagRule,1602: Invalid Number of Tags: 2 (max 2)
May 24 17:28:29 user    warn    kernel: [ERROR vlan] vlanIoctl ,530: Failed to Insert Tag Rule in atm0 (tags=2, dir=0)
May 24 17:28:29 user    info    kernel: device atm0.1 entered promiscuous mode
May 24 17:28:29 user    info    kernel: device atm0 entered promiscuous mode
May 24 17:28:29 daemon  notice  syslog: pppd 2.4.1 started by admin, uid 0
May 24 17:28:29 user    info    kernel: br0: port 6(atm0.1) entering forwarding state
May 24 17:28:30 daemon  notice  syslog: PPP: Start to connect ...
May 24 17:28:56 daemon  notice  syslog: PPP: Start to connect ...
May 24 17:28:57 daemon  crit    syslog: PPP server detected.
May 24 17:28:57 daemon  crit    syslog: PPP session established.
May 24 17:28:58 user    warn    kernel: wp1=3c wp2=00
May 24 17:28:58 user    warn    kernel: e126wp1=00 wp2=3c
May 24 17:28:58 daemon  crit    syslog: PPP LCP UP.
May 24 17:28:59 daemon  crit    syslog: Received valid IP address from server. Connection UP.
May 24 17:29:15 user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0.1 OUT= MAC= SRC=64.94.18.71 DST=105.228.182.104 LEN=52 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=111 ID=16934 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61017 DPT=64481 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
May 24 17:29:18 user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0.1 OUT= MAC= SRC=195.59.54.103 DST=105.228.182.104 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=2661 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62203 DPT=64446 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
May 24 17:29:19 user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0.1 OUT= MAC= SRC=195.59.54.103 DST=105.228.182.104 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=2662 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62203 DPT=64446 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
May 24 17:29:21 user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0.1 OUT= MAC= SRC=195.59.54.103 DST=105.228.182.104 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=2663 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62203 DPT=64446 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
May 24 17:37:31 user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0.1 OUT= MAC= SRC=87.109.102.146 DST=105.228.182.104 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=42 ID=49921 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=1449 DPT=80 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
May 24 17:39:24 user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0.1 OUT= MAC= SRC=213.114.250.165 DST=105.228.182.104 LEN=52 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=108 ID=29039 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=58156 DPT=80 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
May 24 17:52:27 user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0.1 OUT= MAC= SRC=27.254.41.97 DST=105.228.182.104 LEN=48 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=24755 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=4123 DPT=445 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
May 24 17:56:33 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
May 24 17:56:33 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: XTM Link Information, portid = 0, State = DOWN, Service Support = ATM
May 24 17:56:33 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: Connection DOWN, LinkActiveStatus=0x0
May 24 17:56:35 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
May 24 17:56:44 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
May 24 17:56:48 user    info    kernel: device atm0.1 left promiscuous mode
May 24 17:56:48 user    info    kernel: device atm0 left promiscuous mode
May 24 17:56:48 user    info    kernel: br0: port 6(atm0.1) entering disabled state
May 24 17:56:49 daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. Connection DOWN.
May 24 17:56:49 daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. PPP connection DOWN.
May 24 17:56:49 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
May 24 17:56:53 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 message exchange
May 24 17:56:53 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link up, Bearer 0, us=1087, ds=4160
May 24 17:56:53 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: XTM Link Information, portid = 0, State = UP, Service Support = ATM
May 24 17:56:53 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: Connection UP, LinkActiveStatus=0x1, US=1087000, DS=4160000
May 24 17:56:56 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: Connection DOWN, LinkActiveStatus=0x0
May 24 17:56:56 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmrt: MAC address: cc b2 55 45 e5 c4
May 24 17:56:56 user    warn    kernel: [DoCreateDeviceReq.2367]: register_netdev
May 24 17:56:56 user    warn    kernel: [DoCreateDeviceReq.2369]: register_netdev done
May 24 17:56:56 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: Connection UP, LinkActiveStatus=0x1, US=1087000, DS=4160000
May 24 17:56:56 user    warn    kernel: BCMVLAN : atm0 mode was set to RG
May 24 17:56:56 user    warn    kernel: [ERROR vlan] bcmVlan_insertTagRule,1602: Invalid Number of Tags: 2 (max 2)
May 24 17:56:56 user    warn    kernel: [ERROR vlan] vlanIoctl ,530: Failed to Insert Tag Rule in atm0 (tags=2, dir=0)
May 24 17:56:57 daemon  notice  syslog: pppd 2.4.1 started by admin, uid 0
May 24 17:56:57 user    info    kernel: device atm0.1 entered promiscuous mode
May 24 17:56:57 user    info    kernel: device atm0 entered promiscuous mode
May 24 17:56:57 user    info    kernel: br0: port 6(atm0.1) entering forwarding state
May 24 17:56:57 daemon  notice  syslog: PPP: Start to connect ...
May 24 17:57:03 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
May 24 17:57:03 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: XTM Link Information, portid = 0, State = DOWN, Service Support = ATM
May 24 17:57:03 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: Connection DOWN, LinkActiveStatus=0x0
May 24 17:57:05 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
May 24 17:57:06 user    info    kernel: device atm0.1 left promiscuous mode
May 24 17:57:06 user    info    kernel: device atm0 left promiscuous mode
May 24 17:57:06 user    info    kernel: br0: port 6(atm0.1) entering disabled state
May 24 17:57:14 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
May 24 17:57:19 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
May 24 17:57:23 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 message exchange
May 24 17:57:23 user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link up, Bearer 0, us=507, ds=4096
May 24 17:57:23 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: XTM Link Information, portid = 0, State = UP, Service Support = ATM
May 24 17:57:24 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmrt: MAC address: cc b2 55 45 e5 c4
May 24 17:57:24 user    warn    kernel: [DoCreateDeviceReq.2367]: register_netdev
May 24 17:57:24 user    warn    kernel: [DoCreateDeviceReq.2369]: register_netdev done
May 24 17:57:24 user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: Connection UP, LinkActiveStatus=0x1, US=507000, DS=4096000
May 24 17:57:24 user    warn    kernel: BCMVLAN : atm0 mode was set to RG
May 24 17:57:24 user    warn    kernel: [ERROR vlan] bcmVlan_insertTagRule,1602: Invalid Number of Tags: 2 (max 2)
May 24 17:57:24 user    warn    kernel: [ERROR vlan] vlanIoctl ,530: Failed to Insert Tag Rule in atm0 (tags=2, dir=0)
May 24 17:57:24 user    info    kernel: device atm0.1 entered promiscuous mode
May 24 17:57:24 user    info    kernel: device atm0 entered promiscuous mode
May 24 17:57:24 daemon  notice  syslog: pppd 2.4.1 started by admin, uid 0
May 24 17:57:24 user    info    kernel: br0: port 6(atm0.1) entering forwarding state
May 24 17:57:24 daemon  notice  syslog: PPP: Start to connect ...
May 24 17:57:51 daemon  notice  syslog: PPP: Start to connect ...
May 24 17:57:54 daemon  crit    syslog: PPP server detected.
May 24 17:57:54 daemon  crit    syslog: PPP session established.
May 24 17:57:54 user    warn    kernel: wp1=3c wp2=00
May 24 17:57:54 user    warn    kernel: e126wp1=00 wp2=3c
May 24 17:57:54 daemon  crit    syslog: PPP LCP UP.
May 24 17:57:55 daemon  crit    syslog: Received valid IP address from server. Connection UP.
```

Can anyone tell me why the connection drops so often? I'm not too sure how to interpret the information here...

Comment: Interestingly, even though my connection is currently up, I get no response from pings to the DNS servers listed in the router

Comment: probably ISP issues....secondary the DSL router box might be having problems (try power cycling).....finally this could be the hardware on your computer and/or driver.....there are a number of lower probability situations but you are going to have to troubleshoot them.

Comment: Every time I call my ISP, power cycling is involved (when I get through to the call center that is). I doubt its a hardware/computer issue because the connection drops for all computers on the network

Comment: then press for either the supervisor or get the problem escalated.